# I can't get my domain to point to my server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain, nameserver

I have bought a domain on Crazy Domains called techitproductions.com And at home i have a Linux Ubuntu Server running Apache, php5, ispconfig, courier mail etc... I have port forwarded port 80, 8888 (for ispconfig), 22 (for Putty).

My question is what ports do i need to portforward for a fully working server, with both SSL, SSH and mail working?

My second question is how do i get my domain pointing to my server? My external ip is static.

Please i need a step by step instructions i am new to Linux servers and the whole website hosting etc...

Comment: ServerFault is not the appropriate place for questions regarding home networking. Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: You might also want to check if your ISP has locked any ports - they often block 80. Also, if its a dynamic ip address,it may be blacklisted by some e mail spam blacklists

Answer (score 1):

If you have bought domain then you should also have some NS servers set up for you. Usually registrars provide web-interface to manage dns records of your domain. You need to have record(s) of type A pointing to the static IP you have.

Example:

techitproductions.com. A 11.22.33.44
www.techitproductions.com. A 11.22.33.44

You probably would need some other records, but that's out of the scope of current question.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create NS records pointing your static IP for your domain name at whichever service provider you register you domain name. That way you can run a DNS server at your IP. Then you should set-up that DNS server with proper zone entry, A, MX etc records for your domain. And then you can host a service.

This is not an answer we can simply answer. You should do some research about services like DNS, WWW etc and understand the basics. Me, 5 years in home networking, still learning lots of stuff about networking.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of service's you want running on the box you could forward your entire NS or use your registrar's DNS  management to create individual A, CNAME, MX, etc... records.

So if you don't want to host all of the domain services on your home box create just an A record that points to your home networks static IP. That will at least get you started with web.

For the services you are mentioning above I would need at least:

80 HTTP
443 HTTPS
25 SMTP
22 SSH
21 FTP

I would also suggest installing a management tool if this is all new to you. I like virtualmin. That could help manage ya and their support forum is pretty fantastic for open source.